# linux glxgears throws "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication"

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, openssh

Logged in to a linux redhat-6 machine using ssh -X root@machineip and then running **glxgears** works.
However switching to another user **"su - notes"** and then trying to run glx gears does not work.

** This works**

```
# ssh -X root@15.218.114.240
[root@iwf1114240 ~]# glxgears
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:10.0"
      after 123 requests (42 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

** The below commands does not work**

```
[root@iwf1114240 ~]# su - notes

[notes@iwf1114240 ~]$ glxgears
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: couldn't open display localhost:10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy root's .Xauthority file over to note's home directory.